# Passing parameters to stored procedure in sql server

Tags: sql

I have a delete SP which performs actions on multiple tables and takes in 3 parameters. I have a table with 100s of records with the 3 parameters needed for the SP.

I am trying to figure out a way to call the SP for each row in the table and trigger the SP.

For example: Consider Sp: up_form_delete. The form has data stored across multiple tables and takes in parameters form_id,account_id and created_date. I have a temp table with these parameters. I need to EXEC up_form_delete 'form_id', 'account_id' , 'created_date' for all the records present in the temp table

Any ideas on how to do achieve this?

Comment: With a cursor.  The syntax for which will depend on what database server software you're using

Answer (score 0):

You can use a cursor which traverses all the rows and for each row you can call the stored procedure.

Here is an example from MSDN Blog:

---

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @vendor_id int, @vendor_name nvarchar(50),
    @message varchar(80), @product nvarchar(50);

PRINT '-------- Vendor Products Report --------';

DECLARE vendor_cursor CURSOR FOR 
SELECT VendorID, Name
FROM Purchasing.Vendor
WHERE PreferredVendorStatus = 1
ORDER BY VendorID;

OPEN vendor_cursor

FETCH NEXT FROM vendor_cursor 
INTO @vendor_id, @vendor_name

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    PRINT ' '
    SELECT @message = '----- Products From Vendor: ' + 
        @vendor_name

    PRINT @message

    -- Declare an inner cursor based   
    -- on vendor_id from the outer cursor.

    DECLARE product_cursor CURSOR FOR 
    SELECT v.Name
    FROM Purchasing.ProductVendor pv, Production.Product v
    WHERE pv.ProductID = v.ProductID AND
    pv.VendorID = @vendor_id  -- Variable value from the outer cursor

    OPEN product_cursor
    FETCH NEXT FROM product_cursor INTO @product

    IF @@FETCH_STATUS <> 0 
        PRINT '         <<None>>'     

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN

        SELECT @message = '         ' + @product
        PRINT @message
        FETCH NEXT FROM product_cursor INTO @product
        END

    CLOSE product_cursor
    DEALLOCATE product_cursor
        -- Get the next vendor.
    FETCH NEXT FROM vendor_cursor 
    INTO @vendor_id, @vendor_name
END 
CLOSE vendor_cursor;
DEALLOCATE vendor_cursor;
```